# MSSQL 2008 Update record if column matches value from same column in another record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First time asking a question here.  To give a little background we have a database that contains some configuration information for PCs.  These configurations have a field for the serial number in them as well as a field for a contact (who uses the PC).  The contact field was always manually set and now we have moved to a new naming scheme which means that all the configuration records have been recreated with new names.  We need to update the new records being created with the contact value from the old record, all the records are in the same table called 'Config'

Example;

OLD: `machineid.location`

NEW: `location.machineid`

I have been able to write a SELECT query to select the records that match serial numbers however I'm having a hard time turning it into an UPDATE query so that the 'Contact' field on the new record can be set with the 'Contact' field from the old record.  The current SELECT statement I have is below;

```
SELECT *
FROM Config ta1
JOIN Config ta2 on ta1.Config_ID != ta2.Config_ID
WHERE ta1.Serial_Number = ta2.Serial_Number AND 
(ta1.Serial_Number is not null OR ta1.Serial_Number = ' ') AND
ta1.Config_Name != ta2.Config_Name
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been digging around on here but have not had too much luck.

Comment: How can you identify which `Config` record is for the old machine and which is for the new machine?  Sample data would really help clarify the logic.

Answer (score 0):

ta1 is the new record and ta2 is the old one, correct?  And the name of the column to update is Contact?  This should work then:

```
UPDATE Config
SET Contact = ta2.Contact
FROM Config ta1
JOIN Config ta2 on ta1.Config_ID != ta2.Config_ID
WHERE ta1.Serial_Number = ta2.Serial_Number AND 
(ta1.Serial_Number is not null OR ta1.Serial_Number = ' ') AND
ta1.Config_Name != ta2.Config_Name
```

Probably want to wrap it in a BEGIN/ROLLBACK structure and add a SELECT after the UPDATE in the transaction it to make sure you're getting what you want, but that should do it.